# Problem with drawing from code

Tags: wpf

I have XAML that draws an arrow and I've tried unsuccessfully to convert this XAML to code:
the upper arrow is the XAML and the lower is the code.

Can someone tell me what have I done wrong in the code ? I would like it to looks exactly like the XAML one.

[image]

XAML:

```
 <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Rectangle>
        <Rectangle.Fill>
            <DrawingBrush Stretch="Uniform">
                <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                    <DrawingGroup>
                        <DrawingGroup.Children>
                            <GeometryDrawing Geometry="F1 M 3.64665,5.62366C 5.73362,3.09485 8.89196,1.48303 12.4268,1.48303C 16.1132,1.48303 19.3901,3.23596 21.4694,5.95398">
                                <GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                                    <Pen Thickness="2.4" LineJoin="Round" Brush="Black"/>
                                </GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                            </GeometryDrawing>
                            <GeometryDrawing Geometry="F1 M 21.4719,1.21204L 21.4719,5.96594L 16.7181,5.96594">
                                <GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                                    <Pen Thickness="2.4" MiterLimit="2.75" Brush="Black"/>
                                </GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                            </GeometryDrawing>
                            <GeometryDrawing Brush="Black" Geometry="F1 M 21.4593,0.00012207C 22.122,0.00012207 22.6593,0.537231 22.6593,1.20007C 22.6593,1.86267 22.122,2.40002 21.4593,2.40002C 20.7966,2.40002 20.2593,1.86267 20.2593,1.20007C 20.2593,0.537231 20.7966,0.00012207 21.4593,0.00012207 Z "/>
                            <GeometryDrawing Brush="Black" Geometry="F1 M 16.7121,4.76526C 17.3749,4.76526 17.9121,5.30261 17.9121,5.96545C 17.9121,6.62805 17.3749,7.16516 16.7121,7.16516C 16.0494,7.16516 15.5121,6.62805 15.5121,5.96545C 15.5121,5.30261 16.0494,4.76526 16.7121,4.76526 Z "/>
                        </DrawingGroup.Children>
                    </DrawingGroup>
                </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
            </DrawingBrush>
        </Rectangle.Fill>
    </Rectangle>
    <Image x:Name="img" Grid.Row="1"/>
</Grid>
```

Code behind:

```
 public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        img.Source = _createInnerIcon();
    }

    private DrawingImage _createInnerIcon()
    {
        SolidColorBrush lineBrush = Brushes.Black;

        var dGroup = new DrawingGroup();
        using (DrawingContext dc = dGroup.Open())
        {
                dc.DrawGeometry(lineBrush, new Pen(lineBrush, 2.4) { LineJoin = PenLineJoin.Round }, Geometry.Parse("F1 M 3.64665,5.62366C 5.73362,3.09485 8.89196,1.48303 12.4268,1.48303C 16.1132,1.48303 19.3901,3.23596 21.4694,5.95398"));
                dc.DrawGeometry(lineBrush, new Pen(lineBrush, 2.4) { MiterLimit = 2.75 }, Geometry.Parse("F1 M 21.4719,1.21204L 21.4719,5.96594L 16.7181,5.96594"));
                dc.DrawGeometry(lineBrush, new Pen(lineBrush, 1), Geometry.Parse("F1 M 21.4593,0.00012207C 22.122,0.00012207 22.6593,0.537231 22.6593,1.20007C 22.6593,1.86267 22.122,2.40002 21.4593,2.40002C 20.7966,2.40002 20.2593,1.86267 20.2593,1.20007C 20.2593,0.537231 20.7966,0.00012207 21.4593,0.00012207 Z "));
                dc.DrawGeometry(lineBrush, new Pen(lineBrush, 1), Geometry.Parse("F1 M 16.7121,4.76526C 17.3749,4.76526 17.9121,5.30261 17.9121,5.96545C 17.9121,6.62805 17.3749,7.16516 16.7121,7.16516C 16.0494,7.16516 15.5121,6.62805 15.5121,5.96545C 15.5121,5.30261 16.0494,4.76526 16.7121,4.76526 Z "));
        }

        return new DrawingImage(dGroup);
    }

}
```

Comment: There's `Brushes.Black` by the way.

Comment: @H.B - Yes I know, silly me .. thanks for that!
If you do not mind I've fixed it in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XAML you specify brushes only for 3rd and 4th geometry drawings (and pens only for 1st and 2nd ones), so your code snippets are not actually equal.

A small fix for those 4 lines inside the *using* block should do the trick:

```
dc.DrawGeometry(null, new Pen(lineBrush, 2.4) { LineJoin = PenLineJoin.Round }, Geometry.Parse("F1 M 3.64665,5.62366C 5.73362,3.09485 8.89196,1.48303 12.4268,1.48303C 16.1132,1.48303 19.3901,3.23596 21.4694,5.95398"));
dc.DrawGeometry(null, new Pen(lineBrush, 2.4) { MiterLimit = 2.75 }, Geometry.Parse("F1 M 21.4719,1.21204L 21.4719,5.96594L 16.7181,5.96594"));
dc.DrawGeometry(lineBrush, null, Geometry.Parse("F1 M 21.4593,0.00012207C 22.122,0.00012207 22.6593,0.537231 22.6593,1.20007C 22.6593,1.86267 22.122,2.40002 21.4593,2.40002C 20.7966,2.40002 20.2593,1.86267 20.2593,1.20007C 20.2593,0.537231 20.7966,0.00012207 21.4593,0.00012207 Z "));
dc.DrawGeometry(lineBrush, null, Geometry.Parse("F1 M 16.7121,4.76526C 17.3749,4.76526 17.9121,5.30261 17.9121,5.96545C 17.9121,6.62805 17.3749,7.16516 16.7121,7.16516C 16.0494,7.16516 15.5121,6.62805 15.5121,5.96545C 15.5121,5.30261 16.0494,4.76526 16.7121,4.76526 Z "));
```